# Gulp pass argument to series task

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I have a series of gulp tasks

```
gulp.task('build',
    gulp.series(clean, pages));
```

And for example, this is one of those tasks

```
function clean(done) {
    rimraf('dist', done);
}
```

This works but if I try to pass an argument to the task, it gives me an error.
So if I do this:

```
gulp.task('build',
    gulp.series(clean('dist'), pages));

function clean(dir, done) {
    rimraf(dir, done);
}
```

I get **AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: rimraf: callback function required**